# Where to hide PHP to prevent email from triggering

Tags: php, email, twilio, integration

I'm currently using Twilio for an SMS to email integration.

The code Twilio provided needs to live on a public URL in order for the integration to work. There's no reason any human would need to access this URL.

Unfortunately, the code living on a public URL means that random web crawlers can and do load the page where it lives, which triggers a blank email to send. At least I think that's what's doing it?

I cannot use an if...else to see whether any fields are empty because the integration sends boilerplate labels like "body" and "message" automatically (thus, the fields never look empty).

So, I'm wondering if there's someplace in my file structure where I can hide this PHP so that the integration can work but no random pings to the URL will trigger the email.

Edit: this php currently lives in the /usr/share/nginx/html folder as my index.php file. I'm not super experienced and it took me a lot of experimenting to find a place to put it where it actually ran successfully...

Comment: if you change the name `index.php` to something like `7eead553-5a1d-4797-9234-a7eda26369bb.php` - would that work?

Comment: Use robots.txt ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Renaming it breaks the integration (not sure why). I added in a robots.txt file but I suppose I'll have to see whether that works over the next 24 hrs. Obviously, an email still fires when I manually reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You have a couple of options here.

You can [add HTTP basic authentication to your server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04). Then, change your Twilio number's webhook URL to include the username and password in the URL. Like:

```
https://username:password@example.com/index.php
```

Alternatively, within your code you can [validate that the request came from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security#validating-requests) using the `X-Twilio-Signature` header. This would look a bit like this:

```
<?php
// NOTE: This example uses the next generation Twilio helper library - for more
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Security\RequestValidator;

// Your auth token from twilio.com/console
$token = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN";

$signature = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_TWILIO_SIGNATURE"];

$validator = new RequestValidator($token);

$url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'];
$postVars = $_POST

if ($validator->validate($signature, $url, $postVars)) {
  // This is from Twilio!
  // The rest of your code to send the email goes here.
} else {
  // This is not from Twilio. Return a 403 response
  header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
  exit;
}
```

You can read more about [securing your webhook endpoints in the Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security).

Answer (score 0):

you should store the file outside the webroot if possible.

otherwise...

Use .htaccess to `deny from all`

Comment: From what i understand, for php to be accessible via a public URL, it needs to live in the webroot, which might explain why it doesn't really work when I place it outside of that. Can you elaborate on how I'd use .htaccess? It seems like I need a specific IP to allow, which I assume I'd need to get from Twilio?

Comment: see answer by philnash